# Complete graph coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $K_n$ be a complete graph on $n$ vertices. What is the smallest number of edges to colour so that an odd number of edges are coloured in each triangle of $K_n$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use algebraic methods: Let $x_{i,j} \in \mathbb{Z}_2, 1 < i < j <= n$.Than we need to find a solution of the system: $x_{i_1,i_2}+x_{i_2,i_3}+x_{i_1,i_3} = 1$, $1 <= i_1 < i_2 < i_3 <= n$ with the minimal $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n{x_{i,j}}$. But it didn't give any results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $a, b\in V(K_n)$, we will say that $a\sim b$ if $ab$ is coloured. Of course $\sim$ is a symmetrical relation.

Then, given $u, v, w\in V(K_n)$ such that $u\sim v$ and  $v\sim w$, we must have $u\sim w$ (otherwise the triangle $\triangle uvw$ would have an even number of edges coloured), therefore $\sim$ is a transitive relation, so the graph

$$G = (V(K_n), \{e\in E(K_n) : e\text{ is coloured}\})$$

must consist of several complete connected components. If there are $3$ components, however, we can choose a vertex of each and they will form a triangle with no coloured edges, so the number of components must be at most $2$.

With $2$ connected components, one must have $k$ and the other $n-k$ vertices, totalizing $\begin{aligned}\binom{k}{2} + \binom{n-k}{2} = \frac{n^2-n}{2}+k(n-k)\end{aligned}$ coloured edges, which is minimum when $\begin{aligned}k = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\end{aligned}$.

Here is an example for $n = 7$:

[image: graph]